# Is it possible to have the progress displayed when using webpack-dev-middleware like the --progress option from webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, progress, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

I have an express server that uses webpack-dev-middleware.

If you run webpack-dev-server from the cli there's a "progress" option that causes the progress to be displayed on the console. This is a nice to have feature that I would like when using the middleware as well.

Is this achievable or is it for the standalone dev server only?

I searched the documentation but couldn't find anything relevant to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible by using `webpack.ProgressPlugin` before passing it to the `webpack-dev-middleware`.

```
const compiler = webpack(yourWebpackConfig);
compiler.apply(new webpack.ProgressPlugin());
```

`webpack-dev-server` uses `webpack-dev-middleware` under the hood and the progress option is handled in [webpack-dev-server.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/b85a0ceb946589d345c2b41e4d1efb8a5c945f9c/bin/webpack-dev-server.js#L344-L348).

As you can see from that source code, you can also set the `profile` (boolean) option, which shows how long each processing step took.